# Change button style but save default behaviour - NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I started to learn NativeScript..

I have a button and I want to remove his background color so I tried to add this in the css:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

and it's works, but the default style (like the touch effect) was disabled..

There is a way to change specific style attribute of a button without loosing all the rest of the effects?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a <Button>? It seems like you want to change the look n feel of the button to something else. Maybe you just want to add a tap-event to any other element, e.g. a label <Label tap="doSomething" />

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://imgur.com/W3QQelq

Comment: It sounds like you're hoping to apply a ripple effect to something that's clear...

Comment: I don't understood...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ripple effect and a transparent background, it doesn't look like it's possible at this time. I'd open a feature request or make a PR fixing the stylers when using transparent on **Background-Color**

Answer (score 0):

Set the button background color to match the parent's one. Ex: Page bg=blue, button bg=blue, that way he will keep all his other properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve what's needed by applying opacity, z-index, and background-color to a button - wchich allows to make nice ripple effect and tapping sound on any layout element capable of handling onTap event

```
<AbsoluteLayout  width="40" height="60" >
<label top="8" style=" z-index:1;color:#ffffff;background-color:#D63F50;border-color:#d63f50; font-size:14" text="{{alerts_num}}" class="bubble-label"/>     
<button style="opacity:.8;z-index:-1;background-color:#ffcc33" width="45" height="60" />
<image stretch="aspectFit"  height="25" style="margin:20 10" src="~/images/ico_bell.png" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Nativescript ver. 2.0.0